# swiftでstoryboardでUIimageviewのx,y座標の制約をつけたい場合

Tags: swift, storyboard, uiimageview

swiftでUIimageviewを使い、画像を表示して
その画像のサイズをCGrectで指定しているのですが、
この場合、CGRect(x:x座標, y:y座標,width:400, height:400)のように
x座標とy座標も含めなければ動きません。
画像のx,y座標はstoryboardの制約で位置を決定したいのですが、
画像のサイズを指定しつつ、座標はstoryboardで決定するという書き方はどのようにすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

storyboardの制約とおっしゃっているのは**Autolayoutの制約**という意味でしょうか？
storyboardはGUIでAutolayoutの制約も指定可能なツールです。

> 画像のサイズを指定しつつ、座標はstoryboardで決定するという書き方はどのようにすればよいでしょうか。

**書き方**の質問ですので、storyboard上での設定でなく、コードベースでのAutolayoutの制約の書き方と想定して回答します。

また、指定するx、y座標についても詳細がありませんでしたので、以下と想定します。

- x座標：親View（view）から右に10px
- y座標：親View（view）から下に20px

上記の条件の制約を追加する場合、以下のようなコードとなります。

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400).isActive = true
```